# Controller/Observer Canonical Forms

Tags: control, linear

Given $$ G(s) = \frac{1}{(s+1)^2} $$ how do I come up with the following time-invariant realizations?

1) Controllable but not observable
2) Not controllable but observable
3) Neither controllable nor observable

I put G(s) into the controller and observable canonical forms and I found both are controllable and observable.

Answer (score 0):

For example, have you considered the following factorisation, with each term expressed in controller canonical form?

$$\small \frac{1}{(s+1)}\:\times \small \frac{1}{(s+1)}$$

This is neither controllable nor observable. Check it out with \$\small\left[B\:\:AB\right]\$ and \$\small\left[C\:\:CA\right]^{T}\$.